# Can't drag 'n drop terminal window on screen

Tags: unity

Running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with gnome desktop, fully updated.

If I open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) it invariably opens in the upper-left corner of the screen and I cannot drag the window to a different position. I position the mouse pointer in the title bar and press and hold the left mouse button but the or pointer does not change and the window will not move. I can hide/maximize/minimize the window using the buttons at the right hand side of the title bar. I can resize it by gripping the corners or edges.

This problem also affects gedit and calculator windows but not chrome, VLC or most other apps I use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has disappeared and I am not sure why. One day I replaced the mouse I was using with a different (newer) one and upgraded from Ubuntu 20.xx to 22.xx. I am not sure what got fixed or why but I can drag and drop terminal windows now too.

Thanks to all who took the time to read and post. Consider the issue resolved.